# Lebesgue Measure of Intersection of two sets

Tags: analysis

I have a one question relating to one property of Lebesgue Measures. 
If I have two sets, say $A \subset B $ and $B \subset C$ (closed or open) and Lebesgue measure is denoted by $\lambda$. Then my question is, what is the solution of following:

$$\lambda (C\backslash A \cap  C\backslash B)=?$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $(C\backslash A) \cap  (C\backslash B)=C\backslash(A\cup B)=C\backslash B$. Then
$$\lambda ((C\backslash A) \cap ( C\backslash B))=\lambda(C\backslash B)=\lambda(C)-\lambda(B)$$
if $C$ and $B$ are measurable.

Comment: thanks dear for this support

Comment: This holds only if the measure of C is finite.

Comment: You mean the measure of B has to be finite. You only get in troubles when subtracting infinity. So OP should add that assumption otherwise it's not true in general.